# Necessary and sufficient conditions so that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges

Tags: general-topology

> Let $d\in\mathbb{N^*}$. Consider a vector space $F=\mathbb{R^d}$. Let $(x_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a sequence in $F$. With $n\in\mathbb{N^*}$, we define $x_{n}^k, k=1,...d$ as the k-th composant of $x_{n}$. Find the three necessary and sufficient conditions of the $d$ sequences $(x_{n}^k)_{n\ge0}$ so that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

I don't understand this problem. Each sequence $(x_{n}^k)_{n\ge0}$ converges is enough to conclude that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, convergence of the sequence is equivalent to the convergence of all its coordinate sequences. Maybe your textbook wants you to prove this?

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand why there are three conditions. I just found one.